# This wordpress method of displaying image alt and title seems dirty

Tags: php, wordpress

After grappling around with Loops and Wordpress functions, this was the only way I came up with to automatically display "featured" images with `alt == excerpt` and `title == title`.

Is this the most efficient way to do it?

```
<?php
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'Featured')); 
    if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $alt = get_the_excerpt();
    $title = get_the_title();
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('alt' => $alt, 'title' => $title, 'class' => 'bigImg') ); 

    endwhile; endif; 
?>
```

What bugs me the most is the fact I'm defining the excerpt and title in the loop and because of that I have to also display my hash array in the loop as well. There's just something about it that doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ may be a help to you.

Answer (score 1):

*Why not just `global $post;` and then use `$post['post_title']` where you need it?*

**BUT** using the `get_the_*()` functions **will also apply filters** to those values and **YOU WANT THAT**!

**PS**: *Not really sure if I got the question right but you're complaining about two variables that seem redundant to you. You can always `unset($alt, $title)` them when you're done!*

Comment: Thanks for your help :), I think there's a more standard convention of going about setting the alt and title. The unset variables was helpful.

Comment: @KyleJoseph There isn't one. See [**documentation here** ^](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail). Unless you are willing to build your `IMG` markup by hand... which you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks again. This is what puzzles me most ` 'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $wp_postmeta->_wp_attachment_image_alt )), ` if I could apply that and shove it into an $attribute I could just call it in?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use the `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`, `<?php the_title(); ?>` and `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` without the need to define them.

I am assuming that you are displaying a single featured post. Why not add some HTML and CSS to style your loop? Below is what I would use.

```
<?php query_posts( '$cat=1' . '&posts_per_page=1' );
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="column">

<div class="thumbnail"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(254,254), 'thumbnail'); ?></div>
    <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <div class="post">
        <p>Posted in <a href="<?php $category = get_the_category();?>">
        <?php echo $category[0]->cat_name;?></a> <br />on <?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
       </div>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</article>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

`$cat` is the category and you can find it from wordpress on what is the category for "Featured". If you want to show more than 1 post, you can change the `&posts_per_page=1` to whatever number you want.

Comment: Thanks Jonnny I am new here so I didn't know how to format that because it wasn't showing, but when I added a space it works. Thanks :)

Comment: :) Thanks Adrian. I have the post styled already elsewhere this was just a the php on it's barebones.

Comment: Sure thing. What I use for my loop is as above if you remove the styling elements (and the display of category name).